# How to load Login Error page with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Currently I have a login page (login.html) with nothing but a login form on it. 
I also have an error login page (error.html) with nothing but a login form on it and a sentence stating that you have entered wrong credentials.

How can I replace login.html with error.html without reloading the browser using ajax?

BTW.. I am using this login form in a jquery slide down panel.
http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/

Comment: Don't use another page..just print the ajax response in a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution to change HTML between `<body></body>`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "login.html",
  dataType: "text",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    $(document.body).html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: So would I replace your code with this...

//if username or password is blank, send to errorlogin.html
if ((!$username) || (!$password)) 
{

 header("Location:$base_dir/errorlogin.html");
 exit;
}

Comment: IMHO you should find another solution, because changing WHOLE PAGE with ajax is worst option i ever seen.